# Permutation of a string using backtracking : Maximum recursion limit reached

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    #print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
    i = 0
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int], i]:
        
        out = []
        if len(nums) == 1:
            out.append([nums])
        print(out)

        #out = []
        arr = []
        if i == len(nums)-1:
            out.append(arr)
           
        for j in range(i,len(nums)):
            i = 0
        
        
            nums[i],nums[j] = nums[j],nums[i]
            #i+=1
            self.permute(nums,i+1)
            nums[i],nums[j] = nums[j],nums[i]
            
        return out
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/ Given an array nums of
distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can
return the answer in any order.

Error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling
a Python object
    if i == len(nums)-1: Line 6 in permute (Solution.py)
    [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
    self.permute(nums) Line 12 in permute (Solution.py)
    self.permute(nums) Line 12 in permute (Solution.py)
    self.permute(nums) Line 12 in permute (Solution.py)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I have added the code and questions is : https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/

Comment: @Tushar, Stack Overflow doesn't work that way. You have to ask a _specific_ question about your code / technique. You can't just dump your code and the prompt and expect people to figure out and solve the problem for you. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) You get this error because recursion can only be done up to a certain limit and your function exceeds that limit. You're going to have to try a smarter approach than brute-force to get this to work.

Comment: @TusharKumar Please put a look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957455/941531) of your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your recursive algorithm idea I modified your code to make it work:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVDLCsIwELz3Kxa8JBiKj1tBb36Bx5JD0a1G0k1IE9Cvr0lrqxVvzmnJTGZn1j781dC26066als4Gh28MlRkEHHGGiy6JnhkLepaAIWmFaBgBysBJvg4lJIP6gRVR3K/A43EkvaDSog/8spapHPPloXkM96hD46SLJvea@PgBorAVXRBpsTb/Mu9t1RySFneZAz3msTIzfSpUj72G5stYd03439ZZz8aTZx1ijwbT834lKGMR43bNwK2knNYwOFeNVZj1nVP)

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums, i = 0, out = []):
        if i >= len(nums):
            out.append(nums[:])
            return out

        for j in range(i, len(nums)):
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
            self.permute(nums, i + 1, out)
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
            
        return out
        
print(Solution().permute([0, 1, 2, 3])) # Example
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 2], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2, 1], [0, 3, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 3, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 3, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 3], [2, 1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 1, 3], [2, 0, 3, 1], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 1, 0], [3, 1, 2, 0], [3, 1, 0, 2], [3, 2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 0, 1], [3, 0, 2, 1], [3, 0, 1, 2]]
```

Algorithm outputs unsorted order, if you need sorted order then you can sort returned result using standard `sorted()`.

Comment: Thanks, Arty! I was unable to write i (index) in the right manner and in each loop was initiating it to 0. Understood the mistake

Comment: @TusharKumar If my answer was correct and/or at least useful somehow you may Accept and/or UpVote it. Accepting is done next way - at the beginning of my answer to the left from its top there is Check-Mark to accep. UpVoting is located in same place near check mark there is an upper arrow for up-voting. Thanks!